# Пользовательский рендер ToolStrip

Tags: c++, c++-cli

я хочу сделать красивый рендер для ToolStrip, но все руководства и гайды написаны на С#.

Вот пример https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29497/Custom-Rendering-for-the-ToolStrip-MenuStrip-and-S

Я попробовал портировать этот код, но у меня не особо получилось, так как я не очень разбираюсь в C#.

Как сделать также только на C++/CLI?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот кому нужно...

CustomColorTable.h

```
namespace YourNamespace
{
    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;
    public ref class CustomColorTable : public System::Windows::Forms::ProfessionalColorTable {
    public:
        Color _color = Color::DeepPink;
    public:
        property Color MenuBorder
        {
        public: virtual Color get() override
        {
            return _color;
        };
        };
    public:
        property Color MenuItemBorder
        {
        public: virtual Color get() override
        {
            return _color;
        };
        };
    public:
        property Color MenuItemPressedGradientBegin
        {
        public: virtual Color get() override
        {
            return _color;
        };
        };
    public:
        property Color MenuItemPressedGradientEnd
        {
        public: virtual Color get() override
        {
            return _color;
        };
        };
    public:
        property Color MenuItemPressedGradientMiddle
        {
        public: virtual Color get() override
        {
            return _color;
        };
        };
    public:
        property Color MenuItemSelected
        {
        public: virtual Color get() override
        {
            return _color;
        };
        };
    public:
        property Color MenuItemSelectedGradientBegin
        {
        public: virtual Color get() override
        {
            return _color;
        };
        };
    public:
        property Color MenuItemSelectedGradientEnd
        {
        public: virtual Color get() override
        {
            return _color;
        };
        };
    public:
        property Color MenuStripGradientBegin
        {
        public: virtual Color get() override
        {
            return _color;
        };
        };
    public:
        property Color MenuStripGradientEnd
        {
        public: virtual Color get() override
        {
            return _color;
        };
        };
    };
}
```

В вашей форме с MenuStrip

```
#include "CustomColorTable.h"

namespace YourNamespace 
{
    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;
    using namespace System::Resources;
    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this->MenuStrip1->RenderMode = System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripRenderMode::System;
            this->MenuStrip1->Renderer = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripProfessionalRenderer(gcnew CustomColorTable()));
...
```

Также можно сделать и для ToolStrip только нужно поменять названия свойств в CustomColorTable.h

Названия можно взять [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.professionalcolors?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=net-5.0)